# how to change the formatting of chart legends

Tags: c#, .net, epplus

I want to set a number format of the lengends on a chart with the next format:

300.000 kWh

Actually i get 300000.

How can i do this.

I tried do it manually with Excel setting the format of the cell to personalized number format in the dialog cell Format adding this format # "kWh".

With this trick, I can do. But I need to do this when I generate the excel, and not when the excel is generated...

Answer (score 0):

```
cells["kwhcell"].Style.NumberFormat = "#.##0,00 kWh";
```

Comment: Hi, When i use your solution, I get a error format, when i download the excel generated.

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly. You'll have to loop all the cells and do the formatting yourself.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= excelWorksheet.Dimension.End.Row; i++)
{
    string cellValue = string.Format("{0:N2}", Convert.ToDecimal(excelWorksheet.Cells[i, 1].Value)) + " kWh";
    excelWorksheet.Cells[i, 1].Value = cellValue;
}
```

Comment: But, i need to do this, to show the kWh in Vertical Axys legend of chart

Comment: Thats's a whole different question... Your question is about cell formatting, not how to change the formatting of chart legends.

Comment: I have asked this question because I have managed to do what I want manually with Excel. And seeing that I could do so, I decided to ask the question with that approach. But I see that has not worked.
I changed the context of the question.

Answer (score 0):

I sloved my Problem.

This is the correct code to answer my question

```
wsData.Cells[2, (z + 1)].Style.Numberformat.Format = "#0,0 \"kwh\"";
```

and

```
wsData.Cells[2, (z + 1)].Style.Numberformat.Format = "#0,0 \"ºC\"";
```